# Groovy logger is not working when using inside Jenkins jobs

Tags: logging, jenkins, groovy

I have a jenkins job which calls a groovy script. I have used a simple logger (for STDOUT) inside the groovy script. But, for some reason, it is not working at all.

My code looks like this:

```
import hudson.model.*
import java.util.logging.Logger

Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("")
logger.info("I am a test info log")

logger.info("Starting script VersionNumber.groovy 1 ...")

....
```

Is there any way to make it work out?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you checked https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logging

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are referring to the output of the job and not the 'real' stdout of Jenkins. I also assume you are using the Groovy Postbuild script.

In Groovy postbuild there is an available instance of 'manager' which serves as a key to all sorts of operations. See [the plugin page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin) for details.

Writing to the output of the job is done by a logger inside the listener:

```
manager.listener.logger.println "Hello"
```

Getting hold of the 'real' stdout or the Jenkins log file is to my knowledge not possible from within a job.