# Custom logger not being used in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, gradle, logging

The methods from the below Groovy class are invoked by some other pipeline script classes about which I don't know. **All the println statements have been replaced by logger.info.**

```
class ConfigurationPluginInitBase implements Plugin<Project> {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConfigurationPluginInitBase.class)
.
.
.
protected void configureDependenciesResolution(Project project) {
.
.
.
logger.info("Configuring Dependencies Resolution")
logger.info('Does the buildInfo.json exist? {}' , file.exists())
logger.info('The list of dependencies should be rewritten: {}' ,rewriteDependency)

/*Added this as there was no other way to see what happened to the logger instance*/
println 'Is the logger instance created at all???' + logger
.
.
.
logger.info('List: {}' , listToUpdate)
}

}
```

log4j2-test.properties

```
status = error
name = PropertiesConfig

filters = threshold

filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = debug

appenders = console

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c:- %m%n

loggers = console

logger.console.name = ConsoleLog
logger.console.level = debug
logger.console.additivity = false
logger.console.appenderRef.console.ref = STDOUT

rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

The output(only relevant part shown below) on the Jenkins job console:

```
.
.
.
.
Download http://artifactory.net:8081/artifactory/Migration_R148_VR/tools.gradle.plugin/BuildPublishReleasePlugin/v4.0.0.37af2ff/ivy-v4.0.0.37af2ff.xml
Download http://artifactory.net:8081/artifactory/Migration_R148_VR/tools.gradle.plugin/BuildPublishReleasePlugin/v4.0.0.37af2ff/BuildPublishReleasePlugin-v4.0.0.37af2ff.jar
//Printed way before the actual logger statements, when the above artifact is //downloaded from Artifactory for further testing in the pipeline
Is the logger instance created at all???org.gradle.internal.logging.slf4j.OutputEventListenerBackedLogger@efbec93c
apache-commons:commons-collections:null
apache-commons:commons-lang:null
DAP_Framework:DAP_FrameworkExt:null
esapi:esapi:null
opensaml:opensaml:null
openws:openws:null
slf4j:slf4j:null
spring-framework:spring-framework:null
TDE_Ark_Framework:TDE_Ark_Framework:null
TDE_Ark_Infrastructure:TDE_Ark_Infrastructure_CLI:null
velocity:velocity:null
wurfl:wurfl:null
xmlsec:xmlsec:null
xmltooling:xmltooling:null.
.
.
.
[Ripple AlfaClient] Configuring Dependencies Resolution
[Ripple AlfaClient] Does the buildInfo.json exist? true
[Ripple AlfaClient] The list of dependencies should be rewritten: DAP_Framework:DAP_Framework_CLI:1.2.2-integration.adcb14d
[Ripple AlfaClient] List: [DAP_Framework:DAP_Framework_CLI:1.2.2-integration.adcb14d]
.
.
.
```

- The logger that I have configured is probably not invoked
- The run-time instance is of [OutputEventListenerBackedLogger](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/logging/src/main/java/org/gradle/internal/logging/slf4j/OutputEventListenerBackedLogger.java)
- **Even if I make changes to the logger statements, they don't reflect in the output but the new println that I have added does.** This is confusing i.e some changes get reflected while some don't!

I referred to the [Gradle logging page](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html) and threads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35314469/groovy-logger-is-not-working-when-using-inside-jenkins-jobs) and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/job-dsl-plugin/JYPK6ylKsvs)  but I am unclear about the root cause.

Note: I am new to Jenkins pipeline, Gradle and Groovy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you would like to use Gradle’s logging system for your log output from a Gradle plugin?

In that case I would suggest to create/get the logger instance differently. Either use `project.logger.info(…)` or [create a new `Logger`](https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/javadoc/org/gradle/api/logging/Logging.html#getLogger-java.lang.Class-) like so:

```
private static final Logger logger = Logging.getLogger(ConfigurationPluginInitBase.class)
```

Having said that, the reason why your log messages might not show up currently could be that Gradle’s default log level is `LIFECYCLE` – but you seem to only be logging to `INFO`. You can try running Gradle with the `--info` option to see your messages.

Comment: I started with the idea of using the slf4j backed by log4j2. I think Gradle should allow to do this rather than enforcing it's own logger, is my assumption valid? If yes, how do I proceed with it?

Comment: Ok, that was not so obvious from your question (at least to me) … Anyway, where do you have those log statements? It looks as though it was in a Gradle plugin; is that the case? If so, then I’d highly recommend to go with the Gradle logger (which is also based on SLF4J) as that’s what the users of your plugin will expect; using a custom logging infrastructure may be confusing. Otherwise – unless you _really_ need to go with Log4J – I’d personally recommend to also look into Logback which is the [official successor to Log4J](https://logback.qos.ch/reasonsToSwitch.html) (from the same authors!).