# Gradle logging with slf4j and log4j2

Tags: gradle, logging, jenkins-pipeline

I am facing an issue where the slf4j backed by log4j2 statements aren't visible in the console output of a Jenkins pipeline job. The pipeline code is in Groovy. The details are in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53521016/custom-logger-not-being-used-in-jenkins-pipeline).

I flipped through the [Gradle logging documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html) which states:

> You can also hook into Gradle’s logging system from within other
>   classes used in the build (classes from the buildSrc directory for
>   example). Simply use an SLF4J logger. You can use this logger the same
>   way as you use the provided logger in the build script.

Example 4. Using SLF4J to write log messages

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

def slf4jLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger('some-logger')
slf4jLogger.info('An info log message logged using SLF4j')
```

> Gradle also provides integration with the Java Util Logging, Jakarta
>   Commons Logging and Log4j logging toolkits. Any log messages which
>   your build classes write using these logging toolkits will be
>   redirected to Gradle’s logging system.

I am unsure if I understood the above citations. The questions that I have are:

1.In simple words, does it mean that you cannot bypass the Gradle logging?
2.**Is it that the code like below will still invoke the Gradle logging system which has log levels different than slf4j/log4j2?** Here, I am trying to use slf4j backed by log4j2, without even knowing about the Gradle logging(similar to Example 4 in the Gradle logging).

```
class ConfigurationPluginInitBase implements Plugin<Project> {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConfigurationPluginInitBase.class)
.
.
.
protected void configureDependenciesResolution(Project project) {
.
.
.
logger.info("Configuring Dependencies Resolution")
logger.info('Does the buildInfo.json exist? {}' , file.exists())
logger.info('The list of dependencies should be rewritten: {}' ,rewriteDependency)

/*Added this as there was no other way to see what happened to the logger instance*/
println 'Is the logger instance created at all???' + logger
.
.
.
logger.info('List: {}' , listToUpdate)
}

}
```

log4j2-test.properties

```
status = error
name = PropertiesConfig

filters = threshold

filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = debug

appenders = console

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c:- %m%n

loggers = console

logger.console.name = ConsoleLog
logger.console.level = debug
logger.console.additivity = false
logger.console.appenderRef.console.ref = STDOUT

rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

Partial build.gradle

```
.
.
.
dependencies {
    compile gradleApi()
    compile localGroovy()
    compile "org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.0"
    compile "org.ajoberstar:grgit:1.9.3"
    compile "org.ajoberstar:gradle-git:1.7.2"
    compile "com.github.zafarkhaja:java-semver:0.9.0"
    compile "de.gliderpilot.gradle.semantic-release:gradle-semantic-release-plugin:1.4.0"
    compile "com.netflix.nebula:nebula-dependency-recommender:5.2.0"
    compile "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.4.12"
    compile "tools.swedbank.gradle.plugin:qualityreport:v1.12.9"
    compile "tools.swedbank.gradle.plugin:gradle-tde:v1.24.2"

    //slf4j
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.9'

    //log4j2
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.11.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.11.1'

    //Start: Binding slf4j to an implementation, exactly one should be uncommented at a time
    //Use log4j2
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-slf4j-impl', version: '2.11.1'

    //Use logback
    //compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name:'logback-classic', version: '1.2.3'
    //compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name:'logback-core', version: '1.2.3'

    testCompile('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4') {
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy'
    }
    testCompile gradleTestKit()
}
configurations.all
{
    resolutionStrategy
    {
        force 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.12'
    }
}
```

3.Do I need to configure something in the gradle.properties even if I wish to use only slf4j+log4j2 combination?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue? I might be facing the same thing.